# OpenCV Blob Detection & Counting

Tags: python, opencv

I am attempting to count the dark objects in the first image. I've been working with the supplied code using the SimpleBlobDetector (found here on SO), but can't seem to work out how to reliably count each object. As images can be taken from varying heights, the min/maxAreas vary greatly. However, the backgrounds are always white.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkJmW.jpg)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLyTv.jpg)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np


def ResizeWithAspectRatio(image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    if width is None and height is None:
        return image
    if width is None:
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)
    else:
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)


# Read image
im = cv2.imread("image7-1.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params() 
# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 10
params.maxThreshold = 200

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 80
params.maxArea = 450

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = False
params.minCircularity = 0.1

# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = False
params.minConvexity = 0.87

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = False
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01

# Create a detector with the parameters
ver = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
if int(ver[0]) < 3 :
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)
else: 
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)
print(len(keypoints))
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
cv2.imwrite("result.png",im_with_keypoints)
resize = ResizeWithAspectRatio(im_with_keypoints, width=900)
cv2.imshow("Result",resize)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I can do this extremely reliably in MatLab with ~98% accuracy. However, I really want to port this into python. Any ideas on what I can do to produce better/more accurate results?:

```
Rmin = 6;
Rmax = 15;
color = imread('image7.jpg');
grayImage=rgb2gray(color);
imshow(color), title('Image');
[centersNew, radiiNew] = imfindcircles(grayImage,[Rmin Rmax],'ObjectPolarity','dark','Sensitivity',0.965);
[centersNew,radiiNew] = RemoveOverLap(centersNew,radiiNew,5,1);
viscircles(centersNew,radiiNew, 'EdgeColor','r');
numel(radiiNew)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cfGk.png)

Comment: I don't think a blob detector is going to work for you, since you have many overlapping circles. You may use HoughTransform to find circles (which imfindcircles function in matlab uses), but it will probably require some parameter tuning and (more importantly) some post processing, because looking your matlab result it seems like non-perfect circles are rectified (circlefied?). Also I am not sure what preprocess matlab performs and how exactly removeoverlap works.

Comment: You can use this code as starting point: https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html, first obvious parameters are minradius and maxradius.

Comment: @unlut hough transform is difficult to apply cos of occlusion problem. Segmentation can be a solution for this problem because of color varying

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Occlusion does not affect hough transform unless percentage of overlapping area of circles over total area of circles are too high (way more than 50%), and I already said matlab function is based on hough transform. Why you think it would not work?

Comment: @unlut hough transform is edge based, and i thought occlusion would be a problem but i just digged into little bit and learnt you are right, sorry for misguiding